# Handle 100K Inserts and Updates using JDBC Template

Tags: java, spring-boot, jdbctemplate

I want to handle 100k Inserts or Updates daily using spring boot dynamically. The column names will be dynamic. I will not know the model upfront.

currently framing the insert or update SQL and executing those using jdbcTemplate.batchUpdate(query) whereas query is the string array. I am seeing this method is very slow. How we can Improve the performance? Is this achievable via Hibernate?

```
String[] query
try {
jdbcTemplate.batchUpdate(query);
status="Success";
}catch(Exception e) {
logger.error("Insert or Update Query Failed:"+query);
logger.error("Error:"+e.getMessage());
}
```

Comment: This isn't JdbcTemplate's fault; you're inserting and updating **100,000+ records**.  Can you go this in batches to run at specific times of day?  Can you look to optimize how you perform the insert?  Does your DBMS support a suitable upsert mechanism?

Comment: Probably a library like Spring batch that supports this kind of operations in chunks is suitable for your needs.

Comment: @geoandri:  At *some* point, you must tackle the database.  Who's to say that the OP's table isn't fully and entirely indexed, making any insertion or deletion incredibly expensive?

Comment: have you measured time to execute 100000+ queries in database directly without any Java?

Comment: Your question is very broad. Can you be more specific? What does *very slow* mean? How many records can you update or insert per second? Can you provide an example of the query so we can get an idea of how complex it is and where the most potential for optimization is?

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure to add appropriate indexing for your columns. If indexes are missing, the update and select statements would consume lot of time.